# How to resolve the lack of subtraction assignment ( -= ) operator?

Tags: function, variable-assignment, subtraction, easing

I would like to use an easing function from website: https://easings.net/#easeOutBounce

The actual code is:

```
function easeOutBounce(x: number): number {
const n1 = 7.5625;
const d1 = 2.75;

if (x < 1 / d1) {
    return n1 * x * x;
} else if (x < 2 / d1) {
    return n1 * (x -= 1.5 / d1) * x + 0.75;
} else if (x < 2.5 / d1) {
    return n1 * (x -= 2.25 / d1) * x + 0.9375;
} else {
    return n1 * (x -= 2.625 / d1) * x + 0.984375;
}
}
```

Unfortunately I have to replicate this function in a programming language which doesn't have the operator called -= or subtraction assignment. How can I code the function without it?

Comment: Which language do you have in mind? Breaking up into multiple statements should work for any language, even those that only only have “plain” assignment. Also in certain languages using and modifying a variable in a same expression is not well defined.

Comment: AviSynth http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Operators